# rxjs - Angular: How to wait for an Observable function, to call another function that returns an Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have 2 API calls in a service that each return an Observable, and in my component I have some condition that, if true, I must call both those functions, but I need to wait for the get() call, so that I can execute the post function with arguments returned from the get call. If false, I just want to call the post function with the already defined arguments.

service:

```
  get(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<any>('get path');
  }

  post(data: data) {
    return this.http.post<any>('post path', {data: data});
  }
```

component:

```
  execute() {
    if (condition) {
      this.service.get(id).subscribe( (res) =>
        // ...
        this.data = res.data;
        post(data).subscribe(() => // do stuff...);
      );
    } else { post(data).subscribe(() => // do stuff...); }
   }
```

I want to not repeat code for the post call, or if not at all possible, just not use a subscribe() inside another subscribe(). How can I do this? without async await.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When starting rx I found it very helpful to use this operator-decision-tree wizard: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/operator-decision-tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use RxJS [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator to map from one observable to another (in your case GET to POST) and use RxJS [`iif`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) function to conditionally return an observable.

Try the following

```js
execute() {
  const getPost$ = this.service.get(id).pipe(
    switchMap((res: any) => {
      this.data = res.data;
      return this.service.post(data);
    })
  );


  iif(
    () => condition,
    getPost$,
    this.service.post(data)
  ).subscribe(
    (res: any) => { 
      // handle response
    },
    (error: any) => {
      // handle error
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could look like the following:

```
const source$ = condition
  ? this.service.get(id) // Get new data
  : of(this.data); // Use already defined data

source$.pipe(
  concatMap(data => this.service.post(data)), 
)
```